# How to get the candies from the candy box?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do you get the candies from the candy box when it is open ? I have tried clicking the candies and I have defeated every boss and enemy and have all items, but I can't get any candy!

Answer (score 2):

You don't get Candy from the box, you get it from the computer (Which is the option next to the box)

Type "help" to see commands. You can add any quantity and type of candy you desire.